# append to text file duplicate content

Tags: php, file

working on windows 10 php 7.0.29

if I run this snippet fo write a new text file

```
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
die(__FILE__);
```

every thing it is ok

### file content

John Doe

### Jane Doe

but if I run it in append mode on a new file again

```
$myfile = fopen("/tmp/newfile.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "John Doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
$txt = "Jane Doe".PHP_EOL;
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
die(__FILE__);
```

### file content is duplicated

John Doe
Jane Doe
John Doe
Jane Doe
John Doe

### Jane Doe

I id all tests I can image but I can not append to a file

Any suggestion ?
Thanks

### UPDATE

if I run the same snippet from shell it is ok

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? In append mode(a) the file pointer is at the end of the file and it's writing. If you want to truncate before writing use w+ mode

Comment: What is the actual issue - it's a little unclear currently? Are you trying to eliminate duplicates from the text file?

Comment: I'm adding lines to a log file
there are not "duplicates" content is ever written more than once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually recommend file_get_contents and file_put_contents since you pull the data as strings and replace the full contents.
This way you can debug with the contents string and any "old" data is overwritten with the same + the new data.

```
$contents = file_get_contents("/tmp/newfile.txt");
$contents .= PHP_EOL . "John doe" . PHP_EOL . "Jane doe";
file_put_contents("/tmp/newfile.txt", $contents);
```

Comment: Andreas thanks but it is a perfomance issue 
do you ever worked on hight traffic site ?
I can not rewrite the whole file for every line to be added
there should be a way to add a line to an existing file

Comment: @TexWiller If you have ever worked on a high traffic site you would have know **not to use textfiles**. If it really is a performance issue, which I don't believe it is since both methods open the file, then you should look at other methods to save your data.

Comment: @TexWiller any news? Is it slower to use file_get_contents?

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the support
It was a htaccess problem index.php were called 2 times so lines in log were duplicated

@Andreas now that is working with 'append' there is less effort than rewrite whole file.
anyway thankyou for the suggestion will be useful for others circumstances